# Прибавить 7 дней к текущей дате

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, где имеется три поля с датами. Дата добавления объявления, дата отправки и дата прибытия.

Хочется написать скрипт где я получаю все старые даты и обновляю их.

1) Шаг 1. Получаю все старые даты.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM vehicle_country
    WHERE discharge_date < NOW()
    LIMIT 50
```

2) Шаг 2. Получаю текущую дату в нужном формате.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
```

3) Шаг 3. Нужно к этой дате прибавить 7 дней.

Вопрос как сделать так что бы $today был + 7 дней. $today = $today + 7. Как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$today = date("Y-m-d", time()+60*60*24*7);
```

или

```
$today = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+7 days"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Передавайте в `date` модифицированную точку времени.

```
<?php
$stop_date = '2009-09-30 20:24:00';
echo 'До модификации: ' . $stop_date; 
$stop_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($stop_date . ' +1 week'));
echo 'После: ' . $stop_date;
?>
```

Для `PHP 5.2.0+`, Вы можете сделать следующее:

```
$stop_date = new DateTime('2009-09-30 20:24:00');
echo 'До модификации: ' . $stop_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$stop_date->modify('+1 week');
echo 'После: ' . $stop_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

По мотивам с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394811/6275986).