# Как правильно прибавить количество дней к дате PHP

Tags: php, дата

> date('d.m.Y', strtotime('10.08.2010') + 667 *86400);

Это неправильно работает дает ответ 07.06.2012 а должно быть 03.08.2012

Comment: Вы хотите добавить дни или года?

Comment: @sanmai, `86400` - это день, то есть сутки.

Comment: Например так: `strtotime('+3 days');`

Comment: Почему ответ неправильный вы считаете?

Comment: Правильный ответ.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Прибавить 7 дней к текущей дате](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534272/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-7-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Можно через известную библиотеку `Carbon`

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

// К указанной дате добавить год и вывести в формате даты
echo Carbon::parse('10.08.2010')->addYears(1)->toDateString();
```

Она очень гибкая, можешь добавлять через методы:

```
->addHours() // Часы
->addDays() // Дни
->addYears() // Года
// и т.д.
```

> [Документация по PHP библиотеке Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Если брать в расчет те цифры, что вы привели, то можно сделать так:

```
$date = new DateTime('10.08.2010');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1Y359D'));
echo $date->format('d.m.Y');
```

Результатом будет необходимая дата

```
03.08.2012
```

После обсуждения с @Эникейщик решил добавить пару моментов. 
Мои расчеты, как вы могли понять, отталкиваются от даты 10.08.2010 и завершаются на дате указанной в конце поста 03.08.2012.

Еще момент. К сожалению автор не уточнил: речь идет о конкретной дате или есть некий массив с различными датами, по которым идет вычисление. В последнем случае подход к формированию результата исходя из количества дней + исходная дата в корне не верен, потому как в году может быть 366 дней. В этом случае, по моему мнению, необходимо прибавлять "2 года" и уже от сюда вычитать 6 дней.

Comment: Откуда взялось P1Y359D?

Comment: @Эникейщик 1Y - 1 год, 359D - соответственно 359 дней. Описание расширения http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.add.php

Comment: Я понимаю, что это означает. В вопросе 667 дней. Откуда у вас год и 359 дней?

Comment: @Эникейщик В вопросе указано "а должно быть 03.08.2012", соответственно от даты 10.08.2010

Comment: Так может автор просто напросто обсчитался? Не нужно подгонять решение под ответ, возможно ответ - неправильный.

Comment: @Эникейщик то, что автор ошибся в расчетах - это однозначно. Вы считаете, что 667 - это правильное смещение даты, ваше право. Я же считаю, что ошибка автора в неправильном указании этого смещения исходя из конечной фразы "должно быть так".

Comment: Если вы так считаете, то и упомяните об этом в ответе. А то вопрос про одно, а ответ про другое.